# SugarCRM 6.5 CE how to properly validate form data using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, validation, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need to check the field `phone_mobile` for duplicate into the database. If a field value is not a duplicate then continue saving.
And if such a phone already exists in the database, then show the alert message and stop the process(form submission).

My actions:

In the file `./modules/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php` connected custom js file:

```
$viewdefs['Contacts']['EditView'] = array(
'templateMeta' => array(
    'includes' => array (
            array (
                'file' => 'custom/include/javascript/custom_contact.js'
            ),
        ),
    'form'=>array(
    ...
```

Works great.

In `custom_contact.js` file overload `check_form(formname)` function:

```
function check_form(formname)
{
    if(formname === 'correct')
    {
       // This part does not work right for me
        var _form = document.getElementById('EditView');
        _form.action.value='Save'; 
        SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);
        return false;
    }
    if(formname === 'EditView')
    {
        // Ajax query works perfectly
        $.ajax({
            url : '/',
            method : 'POST',
            data : {},// some data
            success : function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                if(!data.success)
                {
                    var text = 'The phone already exists';
                    return false;
                }
                check_form('correct');
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the `if(formname === 'correct') ...` block does not work correctly.

I need to stop the work of the form_save and include when necessary.

Please help to solve the problem correctly.I'm new to SugarCRM.

Comment: @Adriano I need to check phone numbers in the database.

Comment: why call some JS function on focus out? or on change of value ? if validation fail, disable Save button at all.

Comment: @Star Please provide an example of how I can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something related to javsacrip/jquery error handling and you can find many logics on google as well.

Try following code:

```
// DOM Ready 
$('input#PHONE_FIELD_ID').on('change', function () {      
    handlePhoneValidation();
    return false;
});

 var clickAttr = $("#SAVE_BUTTON_ID").attr("onclick"); 
 $("#SAVE_BUTTON_ID").attr("onclick","return handlePhoneValidation(); "+clickAttr);


function handlePhoneValidation(){

    clear_all_errors();

    var node = $('input#PHONE_FIELD_ID');
        current_val = node.val();

   /*
    * Your validation will go here
    * if condition fail then return false otherwise true 
   */

    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you share your solution. it would be helpful for other developers.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this another way

```
./custom/modules/Module_name/metadata/editviewdefs.php

$viewdefs ['Accounts'] = [
    'EditView' => [
        'templateMeta' => [
            'form'                => [
                'includes'            => [
                 [
                     // include custom js file
                     'file' => 'modules/Module_name/file_name.js'
                 ],
                'buttons' => [
                    // Override save button and return after click custom function
                    0 => array (
                        'customCode' => '<input type="submit" name="save" id="save" onClick="this.form.return_action.value=\'DetailView\'; this.form.action.value=\'Save\'; return check_custom_data(\'EditView\'); " value="'.$GLOBALS['app_strings']['LBL_SAVE_BUTTON_LABEL'].'">',
                    ),
                    'CANCEL',
```

After

modules/Module_name/file_name.js:

```
// Function check_custom_data() :

function check_custom_data(formname)
{
    if(formname === 'correct')
    {
        var _form = document.getElementById('EditView');
        _form.action.value='Save';
        SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);
        return check_form('EditView');
    }
    if(formname === 'EditView')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url : '/',
            method : 'POST',
            data : { }, // Some data
            success: function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                if(!data.success)
                {
                    // Some code
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // If everything is ok
            check_custom_data('correct');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This is working for me.